# Android Stream and Record Audio

Tags: android

I am developing an app to ***Android*** to ***stream radio  and recording of stream***,i use the ***Media Player*** to stream and ***URLConnection*** to record.

The problem is that the ***URLConnection*** is faster than the ***Media Player*** and records in excess.

If anyone has any solution would appreciate the help.

***Fuction to Stream***

```
private void stream(String urlStream)
    {
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
        try
        {
            player.setDataSource(urlStream);
            player.prepareAsync();

            player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener()
            {

                  public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
                  {
                       player.start();
                  }
            });

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

***Function to record***

```
public static void record(final String urlString,final File file)
{
    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                URLConnection conn = new URL(urlString).openConnection();
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

                OutputStream outstream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                int len;
                while ((len = is.read(buffer)) > 0)
                {
                    outstream.write(buffer, 0, len);
                }
                outstream.close();

            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("error record", e.toString());
            }
        }
    }).start();

}
```

Comment: Hi Ludger, provide code where you calling these methods. As it is not sufficient to solve your problem.

Comment: I call these methods in onclick button.The user decides  when he plays and when he records stream but to record the user must to play first

Comment: Pass the stream as parameter in record method. Run two thread in syncronchrous way. One for playing and other for recording.

Comment: I can do the stream and record the problem that records more than you should do